# $z^6+iz^3+i-1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve $z^6+iz^3+i-1=0$. I tried to factor/reduce the equation, but nothing seems to be helpful.

I don't necessarily need the solution to this. But, I want to know what is the right approach to reducing such equations? Where can I practice such problems?

Comment: I think you make progress if you apply sum of cubes and difference of squares formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approaches:

> Look for solutions.

You might be able to spot $z=-1$ as a solution right away. Now we can make progress by factoring out (z+1).

> Apply the formulas you know.

I would think that 
$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ and $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ would be particularly useful.

> Use a tool

You can find the answer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E6%2Biz%5E3%2Bi-1%3D0)

Your next question asks for practice problems. I would think that AOPS books on algebra and precalculus would do the trick. But any good textbook on Algebra 2/ precalculus content should have practice like this in it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :** Letting $x = z^3$, your problem it convert in a quadratic equation
$$x^2 + ix + (-1+i) = 0$$
and the left hand side it can be factored as 
$$(x-(1-i))(x+1)$$

Comment: I think recognizing the equation as a quadratic is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^6-1+i(z^3+1)= (z^3+1)(z^3-1)+i(z^3+1)$$ $$=(z^3+1)(z^3-1+i)$$

Comment: And then one should factor the sum of cubes. $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$